# How to get data partially from Realm database

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, realm, mvvmcross

Some how is it possible to get data from realm partially, a major part of android screen's can't afford to show more than 10-20 items so it's unnecessary to loadup 1000 rows when the user will see just 10-20.
So I found a solution to how to fetch data partially like so:

```
FetchDocumentsCommand = new MvxCommand(
  () =>
    {
      if (//Here I need to find a way to get data for example if I had it as pages from page 1/2/3)
      {
        //The load would execute for some specific page and add it to an ObservableCollection
        //So it becomes less laggy
        FetchDocumentTask = MvxNotifyTask.Create(LoadDocuments);
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => FetchDocumentTask);
      }
    });
```

The problem comes when I try to fetch data from Realm for me it looks like this

```
private async Task LoadDocuments()
 {
   var docs = _documentService.GetRealmDocuments();
   Documents.AddRange(docs);
 }
public IEnumerable<Document> GetRealmDocuments()
{
    return RealmService.Realm.All<Document>();
}
```

My question here can I some how make it less paginated as I get it from realm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realm objects are lazily loaded so there is essentially no difference between loading 10 objects or 1000. From the documentation

> Since queries in Realm are lazy, performing this sort of paginating
> behavior isn’t necessary at all, as Realm will only load objects from
> the results of the query once they are explicitly accessed.

If you do want pagination for some UI feature it's just a matter of populating a results object and then only accesssing the quantity of data you need. Conceptually it would look something like this

```
// load the dogs and only display the first 5
let dogs = realm.objects(Dog.self)
for i in 0..<5 {
    let dog = dogs[i]
    // display dog
}
```

Something to keep in mind though - Realm results objects do not guarantee ordering so you should add some kind of ordering when reading objects in

```
let dogs = realm.objects(Dog.self).sorted(by: "dog_name")
```

that will keep your ordering in place as dogs are added, modified or removed.